# Expressing logic operations as modular arithmetic

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I came across a logic question that was easiest resolved by using arithmetic modulo $2.$ Is there a way to express basic logic operations, e.g. AND, OR, etc. in terms of arithmetic operations in $\mathbb{F}_2$?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:              $1+1=0$ but $1\lor1=1$;  + is XOR

Comment: you could say $x\lor y=x+y-xy$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure:

$x\land y=xy $

and $ x\lor y=x+y-xy.$

Comment: to get $x\lor y=1$ when $x=1$ or $y=1,$ I took $1-(1-x)(1-y)=x+y-xy$

Comment: obviously $\lnot x=1-x$

Answer (score 0):

Use min for $\land$ and max for $\lor$.  For $\lnot$ you can use (1 - x).